# How to convert HTML/Javascript codes to be available for use for Android Application in Eclipse

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, eclipse

How to convert these into Java?

HTML:

```
<head>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="96818">
    <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
       <input id="coord" type="textbox" value="">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 var geocoder;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            $('#coord').val(results[0].geometry.location);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm doing an Android Application Project and I want to use the code to get the LatLng from postal code, so I can display the location on Google Map.
Please help me..

Comment: HTML/JavaScript doesn't exactly work in the same way as Android applications? Maybe you should read up on `Android` and find out how this can be done in Android. The `HTML` portion will probably end up in an XML file, and the `JavaScript` portion will be in the related Activity class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to do this.

WebView is a widget in Android which can display a website or just a html file like a web browser does. The core of WebView is same as Chrome, so if your webpage works well in Chrome, it will work in WebView.

First, put your html codes and JS codes into a html file, then put it in the "/assets" folder of your Android app.

The following codes will display the page on screen, and allow JS to run.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webView=new WebView(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String url = "file:///android_asset/test.html";
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        setContentView(webView);
    }
}
```